# Properties in TestResultsHttpClientBase.GetTestResultDetailsForBuildAsync are null

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I try to get all test results from a speficic AzureDevOps build. I need at least those information from any test result: `AutomatedTestName`, `Outcome` and `ErrorMessage`.

Running `TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestResultDetailsForBuildAsync(this.ProjectId, this.build.Id)` returns all tests, but almost all properties on the test results are null, e.g. `AutomatedTestName`.

`TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestResultDetailsForBuildAsync(this.ProjectId, this.build.Id, shouldIncludeResults: true)`  is also not working.

Is there a way to load all properties?

A workaround is to call `TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestResultsAsync(this.ProjectId, runId)` but there the number of results are limited to 10000. This ends in paging until no more results are found. This is potentially a bottleneck and performs bad, if we have e.g. 500'000 tests....

Comment: Hi @Christian Bumann, not get your latest information, is the answers below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 1):

We can load all properties via below [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.1
```

With optional parameters:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?detailsToInclude={detailsToInclude}&$skip={$skip}&$top={$top}&outcomes={outcomes}&api-version=5.1
```

If you have 500'000 tests, we can use the URI Parameters `$skip` specify the number of test results to skip from beginning.

**Update1**

> A workaround is to call `TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestResultsAsync(this.ProjectId, runId)` but there the number of results are limited to 10000.

We can call `TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestResultsAsync(this.ProjectId, runId, skip number)` to specify the number of test results to skip from beginning.

Please refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.webapi.testhttpclientbase.gettestresultsasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet#Microsoft_TeamFoundation_TestManagement_WebApi_TestHttpClientBase_GetTestResultsAsync_System_String_System_Int32_System_Nullable_Microsoft_TeamFoundation_TestManagement_WebApi_ResultDetails__System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_TeamFoundation_TestManagement_WebApi_TestOutcome__System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) for more details.

Comment: Hi Vito. Thank your for the answer, but using the Rest-Api is not an option for us because we don't want to mix the Rest-Api with the code based API which we are using for other stuff. It would be nice if it works with the code based API.

Comment: Hi @ChristianBumann, I have updated my answer, please check it, we can add the parameter skip in the method.

Comment: Hi @vito-liu-msft, thank you for the answer. I already use this method which you describe in Update 1 to read and skip items. But as the number of returned items is limited to 10'000, this will end in a paging with 50 requests if we have 500'000. We don't have such much tests, but this is an example for a bad case. If using the top parameter in `TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestResultsAsync` there should not be any limit (except. the maximum value of an integer) - without the top parameter 1'000 will be returned...

Comment: If you want to continue to extend the return results, we should contact the Azure DevOps Product team, you can raise it in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21)